# Odoo 9 it shows me the home page but empty

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, erp

When I access odoo it shows me the home page but empty, without menu modules or anything written, just the photo.

Comment: Try to explain properly..
so, we can help you..

Answer (score 0):

This problems happen some times.
one of the case is that the user don't belong to group employee this group is define in base module every user should belong to this group if not, then the user will not see any menu just blank page or a page with only black bare.

did you modify anything or what did you do is it the first installation explain what steps did you do so we can help you.

Comment: I didn't solve the problem but as it was urgent, I did the backup and I reinstalled odoo and then I restored the database. by the way the day before the problem, everything was worked and fine, in the morning I found the problem.